# Cant boot Ubuntu, shows GRUB command shell

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

When I started the system, It boots into GRUB command shell.
I am new to the system and it looks like there is missing kernel.

Snooped around the web for solution, and
I tried boot repair, and got http://paste.ubuntu.com/13143511/

I even tried loading grub with the kernels from live USB to reinstall kernels
but, It took me to Busybox

What can I do to get the system back, I cant lose the files.

Comment: Missing kernel? Nothing would load without the kernel.

Comment: If you could provide `lsblk -f` or gparted screenshot I would be able to provide more specific answer for your system

Comment: yes @StarOS , I chrooted the disk and reinstalled the kernels.

Comment: @reversiblean http://paste.ubuntu.com/13143511/
 contains more information than lsblk -f
sda > sda1 ext4   
       > sda2 ext4  
       > sda3 ext4   
sdb > sdb1 ext2   
       >sdb2          
      > sdb5 crypto_LUKS

Comment: sdb1 is your boot partitiion and sdb5 is your root, right? If so try these: http://pastebin.com/TVnbbCTg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work...

**Boot into a Ubuntu Live Media.**

Use `lsblk -f` or Gparted to identify your root and boot partitions.

**Let's chroot into your existing root,**

Mount your Linux root partition at /mnt

```
 sudo mount /dev/sdbX /mnt/
```

If you have sepearte boot partition

```
 sudo mount /dev/sdbX /mnt/boot/
```

Bind directories, so grub can detect other operating systems.

```
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys

sudo chroot /mnt
```

**Reinstall Grub**

```
grub-install
```

More detailed guide: http://www.linuxdeveloper.space/install-windows-after-linux/ (See under the *Reinstall/Restore Grub*)

Replace **sdbX** with the correct device ids.

Comment: repaired my GRUB as instructed, but now I get an error as Device name required. and then a BusyBox screen that shows /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root does not exist.
previously, I used to get a terminal where I enter my crypt_passpharase.. Help appreciated

Comment: /boot/grub/i386-pc/files.mod not found :(

Comment: Just posting the error won't help at all. Say what you have successfully done and what cause the error..